# Linear Congruential Generator, operators & and >> in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, random

I am workind on Linear Congruential Generator. 
The formula is:

```
Xn+1 = (a * Xn + c) mod m
```

I found out such a piece of code in C++ implementing LCG :

```
class LCG {
public:
    LCG();
    LCG(unsigned int newSeed);
    ~LCG();
    void setSeed(unsigned int newSeed);
    unsigned int getSeed(void);
    unsigned int next(void);
private:
    unsigned int seed;
    const static unsigned int a = 214013U;
    const static unsigned int c = 2531011U;
};

LCG::LCG() { seed = 1; }
LCG::LCG(unsigned int newSeed) { setSeed(newSeed); }
LCG::~LCG() { }
void LCG::setSeed(unsigned int newSeed) { seed = newSeed; }
unsigned int LCG::getSeed(void) { return seed; }
unsigned int LCG::next(void) {
    seed = (seed * a + c) & 0xffffffff;
    return (seed >> 16) & 0x7fff;
}
```

In the last two lines of code, I don`t understand the usage of operators & and >>. If anyone can help me, i would appreciate it.

Comment: Do you not know those operators in general or do you not understand their application in this context?

Comment: Of course, in this context.

Comment: The last operator divides generated random value by 2^16. Than cut last bit by applying bitmask. This is probably used to select specific part of generated value.

Comment: The first `&` is useless. Even if an `unsigned int` has "too many bits", there is no way for them to ever affect the lower bits. Only the low 31 bits will ever matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first "&" is doing the "mod" in your formula, with m=2^32. (Presumably this is for a 64-bit-int architecture since it would be a no-op for 32-bit ints.)

The second line is doing integer divide by 2^16 followed by (mod 2^15) -- mathematically equivalent to (seed / 65536) % 32768.

The reason for the alternative ways of calculating these is the almost certain time efficiency of those "bitwise" operators over the equivalent "mathematical" operations.

Comment: The first `&` is effectively a nop on 64bit too, it might compile to some instruction but it cannot affect the result.

Comment: While it doesn't affect the return value of next(). it certainly affects the value of seed, which is evidently important given that there is a getseed() method.

Comment: You can move the `&` to the getseed if you really need it of course

Comment: It also prevents overflow of subsequent (seed*a+c) operations, overflow being a condition with undefined results in c++.

Comment: It's only UB for signed types though, besides if that was a concern the code would be wrong on 32bit systems

Comment: Correct about "wrong on 32bit", but I also found this: "Moreover, integral signed overflow in C++ is not guaranteed to wrap around, since two's complement arithmetic is not required."

Comment: Yes that's what would have applied if signed types had been used, that would have been bad